# Different coding for nested and crossed random effects in lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme

I want to use liner mixed effect model to analyse data from a within-subject experiment. In my experiment, each participant (`PP`, 30-level factor) watch 6 videos (`Video`), and each video contains 50 sentences (`Sentence`) and each sentence has 100 words (`word`).

If I code each random effect uniquely, which means that will be 6 levels for `Video`, 300 levels for `Sentence` (e.g., video 1_sentence1), and 3000 levels for `word` (e.g., video1_sentence1_word1). So in my crossed and nested random effect structure, it will look like: `Lmer = dv~ ResponseTime+(1| PP)+(1|Video)+(1|Sentence)+(1|Word)`, is it correct?

But if I don't code them uniquely, which means that there will be 6 levels for `Video`, 50 levels for `Sentence`, and 100 levels for `word`. In this case, I should use the following structure: `Lmer = dv~ ResponseTime+(1| PP)+(1|Video)+(1|Video:Sentence)+(1|Video:Sentence: Word)`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got this !

This looks correct to me. The only thing I would add is that in the 2nd, model you can write this more compactly, and more expressively as:

```
dv ~ ResponseTime + (1|PP) + (1|Video/Sentence/Word)
```

Comment: thanks @Robert Long! Just to ensure that I understood it accurately, is ```(1|Video)+(1|Video:Sentence)+(1|Video:Sentence: Word)``` handled in the same way as ```(1|Video/Sentence/Word)``` by lmer? In other words, in ```(1|Video/Sentence/Word)```, all three random effects (i.e., video, sentence, word) are handled by lmer?

Comment: Yes, `(1|A/B)` is exactly the same as `(1|A) + (1|A:B)` and `(1|A/B/C`) is exactly the same as `(1|A) + (1|A:B) + (1|A:B:C)` - it's just a kind of shorthand.